# How to use symbols(functions, fields, classes & etc.) declared in a file that includes file where the symbol is used. C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, include, header-files

I have a *function, field or etc.*(let's call it *symbol `a`*) that is declared in file `A.h`, this `a` is used in file `B.h`, so `B.h` includes `A.h`. But `A.h` uses another *function, field or etc.*(let's call it *symbol `b`*) from `B.h`, so `A.h` includes `B.h`. Theoretically it's allowed to work because these symbols may not be variables that stores each other or functions that calls each other making infinity "recursion". But it doesn't work.

**There is a real life example of what I try to say. I didn't include in it all irrelevant details and separation of declaration and implementation in two files.**

File `Application.h`:

```
#ifndef APP_H
#define APP_H

#include "Log.h"

class Application
{
public:
    static void exception(std::string description)
    {
        Log::print("Program throwed: " + description);
        throw description;
    }
};

#endif // APP_H
```

File `Log.h`:

```
#ifndef  LOGG_H
#define LOGG_H

#include "Application.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Log
{
public:
    static void print(std::string message)
    {
        if (message.size() > 200)
        {
            Application::exception("Message is too long");
        } else
        {
            std::cout << __TIME__ << " >> \t " << message << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

#endif // LOGG_H
```

File `Main.h`:

```
#include "Application.h"
#include "Log.h"

int main()
{   
 Log::print("TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT");
    // There are over 200 charcaters. Then it will call method Application::exception from Log::print

    return 1;
}
```

Result:

C2653 on line 17(`Application::exception("Message is too long");`) in file `Log.h`:

*Application: is not a class or namespace name*

C3861 on line 17(`Application::exception("Message is too long");`) in file `Log.h`:

*exception: identifier not found*

Comment: What you're describing, I believe, is [circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/625799/10077).

Comment: You have a circular include. This means one of the headers is not available when the other needs it. Normally you avoid this by forward declaring one types or abstracting it away behind a header both can safely include. In this case, rather than throwing an exception, truncate the too-long message. What's the log user gonna do? Go , "My bad." and try again with a shorter log  message? If you want to catch  people writing too-long messages during development, use an `assert`,  crash the program, and mock them in the lunchroom for breaking the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break the include cycle.

Move the code from one of the header into the matching .cop file. Remove the #include from the header. Move it to .cpp file.

Forward-declare as needed.